# L|K field extension and $deg(f)\nmid[L:K]$

Tags: field-theory

Let L|K be finite field extension and $f \in K[X]$ is irreducible with $deg(f) > 1$. Show that, if $f\nmid[L:K]$ then f has no zeros in L.
Is it true? For ex. $f=x^3+x$ and $[Q(\sqrt 5,i):Q]$. f has zeros in $Q(\sqrt 5,i)$ and $deg (f) \nmid [Q(\sqrt 5,i):Q]$. What's wrong with my example? And how to prove it?

Comment: Yes, it is true. If $f$ has a zero $a$ in $L$, then what is $\left[K\left[a\right] : K\right]$ ?

Comment: Last time I checked there were infinitely many rational numbers, so I removed the *finite-fields* tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(x)=x^3+x$ is not a counterexample, because it's reducible.

If $\alpha\in L$ is a root of the *irreducible* polynomial $f(x)\in K[x]$, then $K[\alpha]$ has dimension $\deg(f)$ over $K$.

By the dimension theorem,
$$
[L:K]=[L:K[\alpha]]\,[K[\alpha]:K]
$$
so $\deg(f)$ divides $[L:K]$.

Comment: Yes of course. Stupid mistake.